# How to read specific excel column and create a new directory with the name of its cells?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i have an Excel file, which contain A,B and C columns and N number of rows, I want to read the C column and create a new directory if not exist for each cell with that cell name as the directory name
any help?? this is what i wrote so far

```
    void CreateDir(String xlsPath) throws IOException {
    ChooseFileClass cf = new ChooseFileClass();
    ChooseWorkSpace ws = new ChooseWorkSpace();
    try {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlsPath));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                String folder = cell.getStringCellValue();
                File file = new File(ws.getWorkSpacePath() + folder);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    if (file.mkdir()) {
                        // directory created
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Directory generation failed");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you only want to read one column, why are you iterating over all of the columns? Why not change your code to just read that one column? See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining @aksappy's code, you can optimize your for loop as such:

```
void CreateDir(String xlsPath) throws IOException {
  ChooseFileClass cf = new ChooseFileClass();
  ChooseWorkSpace ws = new ChooseWorkSpace();
  Cell cell;

  try {
     Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlsPath));
     Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  /* use N Since you know the number of rows */
        cell = sheet.getCell(3,i);  /* Assuming column C corresponds to 3rd column */
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
        String folder = cell.getStringCellValue();
        File file = new File(STATIC_DIRECTORY + DELIMITER + folder);
        if (!file.exists()) {
           if (file.mkdir()) {
           // directory created
           } 
           else {
              System.err.println("Directory generation failed");
           }
        }

        System.out.println();
     }
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your implementation for looping through the excel cells are working fine, you can use the `java.io.File` class to create a directory of your choice.

`boolean isCreated = new File("/usr/tmp/newdir").mkdir();`

In your for loop, do something like the following

```
for(Cell cell  : row) {                                            
     cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
     System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
     String folder = cell.getStringCellValue();
     File file = new File(STATIC_DIRECTORY + DELIMITER + folder);
     if (!file.exists()) {
        if (file.mkdir()) {
            // directory created
        } else {
            System.err.println("Directory generation failed");
        }
    }
 }
```

`STATIC_DIRECTORY` and `DELIMITER` are constants which you will have to assign based on your environment.

Comment: I just want to create directories from the column C only ,I updated the code but still thee is a problem, firs what does DELIMITER mean, the files were created but with random names from the file can you help?